# Is it possible to move from non-concatenative to concatenative morphology?

Tags: historical-linguistics, morphology, arabic

I've been wondering whether it is possible for a language to move from non-concatenative (root-and-pattern, Arabic-style) morphology to concatenative type known from the Indo-European languages? If any language has undergone such a change, what were the reasons behind it?

Comment: Note that Arabic has both catenative and non-catenative morphology (see e.g. http://www.lti.cs.cmu.edu/Research/Kant/PDF/naacl_arabic.pdf). The root-and-pattern system is definitely a very important part of Arabic morphology, but there are also prefixes and suffixes.

Comment: Root and pattern morphology is an extreme form of non-concatenative morphology, which includes things like umlaut, ablaut, tone changes and reduplication. Afro-Asiatic and California Penutian are the only language groups known to have the latter. Do you specifically mean the Arabic-style pervasive type?

Comment: @user6726 precisely. I'm wondering whether there is any Semitic language that dropped it altogether.

Comment: Also note that PIE language would also be quite non-concatenative compared to most modern IE languages standards - not to the crazy degree of Classical Arabic of course, but still quite wild.